# Is it allowed if I draw a human from behind in a painting?

Tags: drawing

I want to paint a nature painting and hang it in my room. But can I add a human only showing the behind?

Answer (score -1):

Drawing portraits is haram as Allah will ask u on the qayamah to make the thing u made alive